# JComboBox actions

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way to distinguish between a JComboBox's index being changed programatically using setSelectedBoundValue and by clicking on the JComboBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *ugly* and truly a *hack*, but works!

The `ActionEvent` contains a field modifiers which in this case is the mouse button id. So using that may help you distinguish between `setSelectedIndex` or `setSelectedValue` and mouse clicks (by the way `setSelectedBoundValue` is not a method on `JComboBox`):

```
box.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getModifiers() != 0) {
            // ~ mouse button pressed ;)
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I know the question says "clicking", but I thnk you have to assume that the user could also use the Enter key to select the item in the combo box. In this 0 is returned. So you can't distinguish from a user action versus a programmer action.

Comment: I said clicking for a reason! :-D

Answer (score 0):

> setSelectedBoundValue

Never heard of that method?

> Is there a way to distinguish between a JComboBox's index being changed programatically

Not really. You can remove the listener:

```
comboBox.removeActionListener(...);
comboBox.setSelectedItem(...);
comboBox.addActionListener(...);
```

You can set your own class variable.

```
manualSelection = true;
comboBox.setSelectedIndex(...);
manualSelection = false;
```

Comment: LOLz,  sorry.  I was mend to write setSelectedIndex.